# "You added %1 to your shopping cart." message not converting in italian language in magento2

Tags: magento2, language-package

`%1 = product name`
when i add a product in cart then magento showing msg
`"You added %1 to your shopping cart."`

> when i add product in cart in italian store
>   so why english message not convering in italian language like below msg
>   `"Hai aggiunto %1 al tuo carrello."`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please tell me this CSV file path ?

Comment: vendor/mageplaza/magento-2-italian-language-pack

Comment: another csv  in app/design/frontend/Meriga/Ecomsolver/i18n

all lines are converting but add in shopping cart msg not

Comment: Is this issue been solved?

Comment: No, this issue not resolved!